# Best application performance

Tags: android, database, performance, sqlite

I have three buttons on an activity and. I want to show some data with button clicks. Which is the best way for application performance. Connecting to database every click or connecting one time on click and storing the data model in a variable and reuse it ? My buttons are reusable more then one time in the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Consider establishing connection to database once in activity's onCreate method
and then once you are done with activity nullify connection in onDestroy method.

And Re-usability > Code duplication

Comment: Thank you Mobin Munir. I want to understand should i do query to sqlite every click or one time in click method.

Comment: Just run a query once and move this operation to a background thread and publish the result on main thread. If your data set is like 10,000 items it may cause UI to jank when the cursor retrieves data.